# Can std::transform be replaced by std::accumulate?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, stl, std

I have a general question. Can we always replace `std::transform` with `std::accumulate`? I have seen this replacement in many cases/examples. So is this possible in theory, and if it is then why `std::transform` was introduced?

Comment: You can replace either with plain loops, and plain loops with conditionals and goto. Why do we have loops if they’re not strictly necessary?

Comment: @molbdnilo Yea you right, but let's say, that the answer to my question is YES(which is not, based on answers).  Then I would like to look for reason why ```std::transform ```was introduced[Making programs more explicit, code is easier to read, make code run faster, etc..].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those two algorithms have completely different purpose.

`std::accumulate` is known as *fold* in functional programming world, and it's purpose is iterate over elements of a sequence and apply two-argument folding operation to those elements, with one argument being result of previous fold and other being element of the sequence. It naturally returns the a single result - a *fold* of all elements of a sequence into one value.

On the other hand, `std::transform` copies values from one sequence to another, applying a unary operation to each element. It returns an iterator to the end of sequence.

The fact that you can supply any code as the fold operation allows us to use `std::accumulate` as a generic loop replacement, including an option to copy values into some other container, but that it is ill-advised, as the whole reason for introducing those (rather simple) algorithms was to make programs more explicit. Making one algo to perform the task which is normally associated to another algo is less explicit and counter-intuitive.

A generic loop replacement algo is [std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each), but with range for loops it became largely obsolete and I have not seen it in use for a long time.

Answer (score 3):

> Can we always replace `std::transform` with `std::accumulate`?

No.  Per [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) `std::accumulate`'s binary predicate `op` has

> `op` must not invalidate any iterators, including the end iterators, nor modify any elements of the range involved, and also `*last`.

So it can't actually transform the range you give it which is a main use case for `std::transform`.

Comment: Since OP never mentioned they are using `transform` on overlapping sequences I am not sure the answer applies.

Comment: @SergeyA The question is *Can we always replace `std::transform` with `std::accumulate`?*  This answers that question.

Comment: I agree with that, but in my opinion it's better to clarify that part. Plain reading of your answer (at least to me) indicates that accumulate can never be used in-place of transform, which wouldn't be true.

Comment: @SergeyA I have.  I quoted the OP's text and gave an answer to that.  No doesn't mean you can never do it.  It just means you can't always do it.

Comment: imho the last sentence makes it rather clear. `transform` can do more than `accumulate`, that doenst imply that `accumulate` never can replace `transform`